# Deserializing Complex Json Object to Dictionary

Tags: c#, json, deserialization

I am having some trouble deserializing a Json string to use in an api wrapper I am currently writing. This is the json string in question:

```
{
   "Search":[
      {
         "Title":"Clerks.",
         "Year":"1994",
         "imdbID":"tt0109445",
         "Type":"movie"
      },
      {
         "Title":"Clerks II",
         "Year":"2006",
         "imdbID":"tt0424345",
         "Type":"movie"
      }
   ]
}
```

This is the method I am currently using to process it.

```
public static Dictionary<string, string> FetchTitlesListDictionary(string searchQuery)
{
    string searchResult = SendRequest(new[] { "?s=", searchQuery });
    JObject parser = JObject.Parse(searchResult);
    var movieDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    for (int i = 0; i < parser["Search"].Count(); i++)
    {
        if (!movieDictionary.ContainsKey((string)parser["Search"][i]["imdbID"]))
        {
            movieDictionary.Add((string)parser["Search"][i]["imdbID"],
                (string)parser["Search"][i]["Title"]);
        }
    }
    return movieDictionary;
}
```

Even though the code above works, I feel it could, somehow, be made simpler.

How would I go about achieving this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if you're open to not using the default serializer, I would just open up the package manager console and type

`Install-Package ServiceStack.Text`

Then it becomes as easy as

```
var myDictionary = JsonObject.Parse(myJsonString)
          .ArrayObjects("Search")
          .ToDictionary(key => key.Get("imdbID"), value => value.Get("Title"));
```

There might be a similar and just as simple way to do it with the newtonsoft serializer, but honestly I never use it, so i'm not sure.

Also same thing as EZI's answer, it's also really easy if you have the objects he created, then you can just

```
var myObject = myJsonString.FromJson<RootObject>();

//if you want the dictionary it's the same thing, standard linq
var dictionary = myObject.Search.ToDictionary(x => x.imdbId, x => x.Title);
```

but if all you need is a dictionary, I would just use the above method, it's fast and easy.

Comment: Thank you! I decided to go with the package suggested by you. It worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

```
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(searchResult);
```

---

```
public class Search
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Year { get; set; }
    public string imdbID { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<Search> Search { get; set; }
}
```

If you really want to convert the *RootObject* to a dictionary, you can use

```
var movieDictionary = obj.Search.ToDictionary(s => s.imdbID, s => s.Title);
```

PS: see [this site](http://json2csharp.com/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer and the link! The reason why I would rather go with a dictionary though is due to the fact that I intend to reuse this code in future projects. So, I need this class to be self-contained.